# Wordpress taxonomy term that also has dashboard page for content?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy

I have a custom post type of services and three taxonomy **terms** registered under the *taxonomy* **service_type**.

These terms are:

- workplace-wellbeing
- presentations-workshops (child of workplace-wellbeing)
- executive-services

**Problem**:

Each of these pages has there own landing page. **YES** redirecting to the correct template file is easy enough, but our sites are built out with advanced custom fields and there's specific elements a client will need to change so I need the dashboard to allow them options to change in-page content and effectively function as though they were a regular page.

How would you guys achieve this?

Comment: So.... what "specific elements" will the client need to change?  Can this not be accomplished using the [template heirarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) for the custom taxonomies?

Answer (score 0):

Custom fields can be added to a custom post type, you do this by either accessing an existing field group or creating a new one. From there go down to the "Location" tab and select "Post Type" "is equal to" "Your Custom Post Types". This should work out for you or you could try using the "Post Template" rule.

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Setsn.png)